# Open URL on click label using VBA Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

How to open webpage, when i click to label in Form? 
For example:

I have url "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" and label on Form Outlook VBA.
When I click on label, i want to open default browser and I want to see this website page - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

How to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use windows API **ShellExecute** for doing this.

To use it, declare it like this atop your form/module code

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute _
                            Lib "shell32.dll" _
                            Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                            ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                            ByVal lpFile As String, _
                            ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                            ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                            ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
                            As Long
```

Then you can do this :

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()

    Dim r As Long
    Dim strUrl

    ' Define the URL
    strUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"

    '  Open the URL
    r = ShellExecute(0, "open", strUrl, 0, 0, 1)

End Sub
```

And it will open the URL in the default browser